# money in sql (mssm)

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to delete the third zero after the point in MSSM

Comment: What is MSSM? I don't know this acronym.

Comment: I think it is SSMS... :) but it is tagged as web-development so no idea.

Answer (score 0):

so do it, nobody is going to stop you;)

note: you should describe problem, provide us with your solution which does not work, or something liek this. Be more exact